# Why is my MOSFET ON when there is no gate voltage and OFF when there is a gate voltage?

Tags: mosfet, high-voltage, switching, high-current

I have been working on a coil gun but am having trouble with the firing mechanism.  My coil gun capacitor bank supplies 400v and instantaneous current of 666 amps based on the resistance of the coil. I am using a TK100L60W MOSFET for the switch.  The problem is that the MOSFET is always on until there is a voltage applied to the gate. Not vice versa (as a MOSFET should function).

Why is that, and is there a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Schematic required. Also MOSFETs aren't controlled by the gate voltage. They are controlled by the gate-source voltage; That is the voltage difference *between* gate and source pins. Terminology wise, "gate voltage" means "voltage difference between gate and circuit ground", which is not necessarily the same as voltage difference between gate and source pin.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different types of MOSFETs, in your case you have chosen a N-Channel MOSFET which requires the gate to be positive to the source by at least 3.7 volts, a few more volts will only help. The MOSFETs use the source as the reference point for gate voltage. If you want to check this look at the data and Vgs (Voltage gate source) it will give you a range and a chart showing how much the devices is turned on in reference the the applied Vgs voltage. Be sure the device is installed properly. Check to be sure the original MOSFET was not a P-Channel device. If this does not resolve the problem post a schematic as requested.